# Problem while adding bibliography file in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, templates

I am using an `IEEE Conference` template for writing a paper and getting error again and again while adding `BibTeX` file into my LaTeX file. Here is the error:

> bare_conf.tex
>   544
>   LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.544 \end{thebibliography}

Moreover, I have not cited any paper from the bibliography yet. (Just added bibliography file here). Here it is:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. The `thebibliography` environment is for when you want to write out the bibliography by hand, while `\bibliography`/`\bibliographystyle` is for when you use BibTeX. Try removing `\begin{thebibliography}{}` and `\end{bibliography}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks but it's still not working

Comment: Is it must to have in-text citations for the bibliography? I'm still not able to show bibtex file's references in references section of the paper. @TorbjørnT. Does it require any sort of package?

Comment: Basically, see Kurt's answer. If you want to add things to the reference list without explicitly citing them, you can use `\nocite{<citation key>}`, or `\nocite{*}` to add *all* entries in the `.bib` file to the reference list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not give us a minimal working example so let us try the following one:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
               [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % <=================== better urls in document
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{This document}
\author{This author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-6]
I have cited this document \cite{einstein} % <==========================
\nocite{*} % <============== to add not cited entrys to the bibliography

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use the bib file created with filecontents
\end{document}
```

Package `filecontents` is used to have bib file and tex code together in one **compilable** mwe. You do not need it for your work.

The following part creates the bibliography:

```
I have cited this document \cite{einstein} % <==========================
\nocite{*} % <============== to add not cited entrys to the bibliography

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use the bib file created with filecontents
```

As you can see you have to cite one or more bibentrys (`\cite{einstein}`) or you can use `\nocite{*}` to add all uncited bib entrys to the bibliography too.
`ieeetran` names the used style to layout the bibliography.

Please copy my MWE to your computer, for example with `mwe.tex`, compile it with the chain

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

Then you get the following result:

[image: resulting bibliography]